# Extracting data from pcap files

Tags: python, hex, ascii, scapy, pcap

I am trying to extract NetFlow Records from a .pcap file, however the data comes up in a non-readable format, like on the attached picture below.
I am unsure how to convert this into a readable format.

I essentially want to get the payload information from the packet capture.

I have tried using Python's scapy library, but I can still not convert it to human readable text. [image: enter i][image]

Comment: Please write your code as ```Your Code``` to be readable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VS Code, you can put a breakpoint after `rdpcap()`, then run the script via Python debugger. In the VS Code debug panel you should be able to expand the object and find readable information.